# Media Wiki Wikipedia Query with Multiple Categories

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to query Wikipedia API and retrieve the subcategories for a list of multiple categories, but it returns a 'bad title' error.  I can't seem to find a solution in the documentation, anyone know if this is possible?  Or do I need to run queries for one category at a time?  Thanks!

Query:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Ice_hockey_by_country|Category:Ice_hockey_by_city&cmprop=title&cmtype=subcat&cmlimit=50

```
"error": {
    "code": "invalidtitle",
    "info": "Bad title \"Category:Ice_hockey_by_country|Category:Ice_hockey_by_city\".",
    "*": "See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
```

Note that this query for a single category seems to work:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Ice_hockey_by_country&cmprop=title&cmtype=subcat&cmlimit=50

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the [`categorymembers` documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers), the `cmtitle` parameter does not accept more than one category. It likely interpreted it as one category named `Category:Ice_hockey_by_country|Category:Ice_hockey_by_city` instead of the two separate categories that you intended.

I guess you'll need to query the categories separately.